# jQuery load character encoding issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please note, I have read the similar questions and the suggested answer frequently 
 popping up:

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
 ?>
```

Did not solve the issue.

**Here's the header of my outer page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        ...
```

**Here is a sample of  inner.php**

```
 <p>£</p>
 <p><?php echo $employee->salary; ?></p> <!-- employee->salary = £30,000 (from db) -->
```

**I'm loading with jquery:**

```
 $('#salary').load('inner.php')
```

**On the output of the outer page I'm seeing:**

```
£
�30,000
```

**inner.php when viewed in the console looks like:**

```
Â£
£30,000
```

I need the output on the outer page to appear as £30,000 and I'm unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: So why aren't you using a HTML5 doctype and UTF8 as your character encoding, and not ISO-8859? The issue is probably that you're saving your files in Windows, and not as UTF8.

Comment: Is the value in `$employee->salary` encoded the same as the `£` above? PHP strings are just byte sequences, so don't expect it to do any automatic transcoding.

Comment: @guest My understanding of encoding is next to none, all I know if I literately type the character '£' outside of the php tags I see `Â£` but when I echo `$employee->salary` I see `£` (when i load inner.php directly without jquery load), so i guess the encoding is different

Comment: I'd start changing the charset=iso-8859-1 for utf8 in the html, just to test... and check the encoding in your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play around with `utf8_decode` or `utf8_encode` and wrap it around your DB Output:

```
<p><?php echo utf8_encode($employee->salary); ?></p>
```

Maybe your DB isn't delivering UTF-8 strings.

If you not have any reason to use the ISO-8859-1 charset on your site other than external text of which you have no control over (and is in fact encoded iso-8859-1), use UTF-8 in

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```